# Install error with Kurento on ubuntu

Tags: maven, ubuntu, kurento

I have gone through all the Kurento questions on Stackoverflow and this error dose not seem to have arisen before.

I have installed the Kurento media-server and java client examples according the installation guides.

I have the media-server running. The problem arises when i go to run the client application. The same issue comes up not matter which one I choose.

**This the Error that is generated:**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-hello-world:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT (/root/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-tutorial:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.kurento:kurento-parent-pom:pom:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-tutorial:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT, /root/kurento-tutorial-java/pom.xml, line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

**This is my pom.xml file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
                <groupId>org.kurento.tutorial</groupId>
                <artifactId>kurento-tutorial</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>

....... more stuff

  <!-- Kurento -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.kurento</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kurento-client</artifactId>
                        <version>6.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.kurento</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kurento-utils-js</artifactId>
                </dependency>
```

I have tried following [this](https://kurento.com/docs/current/mastering/kurento_development.html#working-with-nightly-builds) tutorial for managing nightly builds but this hasn't change anything either.

In the installation guidelines there is no "SNAPSHOT" in the pom.xml sample, I have also tried removing this and but this still had no effect.

I am using a Ubuntu 14.04 system. I am wondering could someone point me in the right direction to solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this error by replacing the 6.1.1 snapshot POM.xml with the 6.0.0 POM.xml. The version of the kurento-media server I was using was 6.0.0 and I needed to get the pom.xml that matched this.

This is a link to the GITHUB commit of the 6.0.0 pom.xml which I used to replace the current snapshot version.

[Link](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/commit/60135f60d69f0a9b206060729e7e9ad0a2499640)

Comment: Nice! You should always try to match tutorials with the actual KMS version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

All Kurento tutorials assume that you are working with stable versions. For working with development (i.e. SNAPSHOT) versions you need to add the Kurento maven archiva to your settings.xml file, because SNAPSHOTS are not published to maven central.

The procedure is explanined [here](http://www.kurento.org/docs/6.0.0/mastering/kurento_development.html). See the section "Kurento Java Client".

Basically, you need to edit your ~/.m2/settings.xml file and add the appropriate repositories there.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the duplicated post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729319/error-trying-to-compile-kurento-java-tutorial-maven-dependency-resolution)

You have checked out the development version of the tutorials, 6.1.1-SNAPSHOT, which depends on other development versions of kurento artifacts. Those artifacts are not published in maven central, so you have three options here

- Check out kurento-java and all related projects, such as kurento-module-creator and a bunch more. You can pull the thread from the pom, they are about 5 projects. You'll have to compile and install all of them in your local `.m2` repository
- Use our [internal archiva repository](https://www.kurento.org/docs/current/mastering/kurento_development.html#kurento-java-client)
- Checkout a tag containing a release version (i.e. `git co 6.1.0`)

In any case, the version of the tutorials should match the version of your KMS, so if you are using a development version of KMS, please use the development version of the tutorials. But if you are using a stable version of KMS, you should be using the matching release version of the tutorials.

You can find more info on how to work with development versions [here](https://www.kurento.org/docs/current/mastering/kurento_development.html#using-development-versions)