# Error trying to compile Kurento Java tutorial [maven dependency resolution]

Tags: java, maven, kurento

After trying the following as specified on the [kurento](http://www.kurento.org/docs/current/tutorials/java/tutorial-5-one2one-adv.html) website,

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-one2one-call-advanced
mvn compile exec:java
```

I get an error like :

> Failed to execute goal on project kurento-client: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   org.kurento:kurento-client:jar:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts
>   could not be resolved:
>   org.kurento:kurento-jsonrpc-client:jar:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.kurento:kurento-jsonrpc-server:jar:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.kurento:kms-api-core:jar:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.kurento:kms-api-elements:jar:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.kurento:kms-api-filters:jar:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
>   artifact org.kurento:kurento-jsonrpc-client:jar:6.1.1-SNAPSHOT ->

How best can i resolve such a dependency issue ?

Comment: solved...thanks igracia :)

checked out a different tag (6.0.0)

Comment: Ok, then please accept the answer, so other users know it was valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have checked out the development version of the tutorials, 6.1.1-SNAPSHOT, which depends on other development versions of kurento artifacts. Those artifacts are not published in maven central, so you have three options here

- Check out kurento-java and all related projects, such as kurento-module-creator and a bunch more. You can pull the thread from the pom, they are about 5 projects. You'll have to compile and install all of them in your local `.m2` repository
- Use our [internal archiva repository](https://www.kurento.org/docs/current/mastering/kurento_development.html#kurento-java-client)
- Checkout a tag containing a release version (i.e. `git co 6.1.0`)

In any case, the version of the tutorials should match the version of your KMS, so if you are using a development version of KMS, please use the development version of the tutorials. But if you are using a stable version of KMS, you should be using the matching release version of the tutorials.

You can find more info on how to work with development versions [here](https://www.kurento.org/docs/current/mastering/kurento_development.html#using-development-versions)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out [Kurento Java](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-java) and run mvn install on that first.  That should place those missing jars in your maven repo, so those dependencies can then be found when you compile the tutorial.